# When the Table was opened by other person, How to select the opened table from the other computer

Tags: ms-access, vb6, remote-access, oledbconnection

When the Table was opened by other person, how to select the opened table from the other computer?

**Using VB 6 and Access Database**

I want to select the table from the other computer when the table was opened by the other person or other software.

```vb
Cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & databasetext.Text & ""
Cn.Open
    
cmdCardEvent.ActiveConnection = Cn
cmd.ActiveConnection = Cn
   
sql2 = "select * from table"
    
If rsCardEvent.State = 1 Then rsCardEvent.Close
rsCardEvent.Open sql2, Cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
cmdCardEvent.CommandText = sql2
Set rsCardEvent = cmdCardEvent.Execute

   
Cn.Close

" & databasetext.Text & " = textbox (Database path)
```

But it showing error:

> could not use; file already use

I want to access the table, if it is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your code correctly you have opened a recordset and should have the data you want with the line

```
rsCardEvent.Open sql2, Cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

When you try to execute the command obejct you still have an open recordset and get an error.